# Laravel Mixed Content: HTTP error behind load balancer, docker.io/bitnami/laravel:9

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I'm using the docker.io/bitnami/laravel:9 image behind a HAProxy load balancer / reverse proxy, and getting the following error in the browser console:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://host.second.top/#' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://host.second.top/css/app.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Following this page:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies
I made my TrustProxies.php as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies as Middleware;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The trusted proxies for this application.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>|string|null
     */
    protected $proxies = ['10.0.0.2'];

    /**
     * The headers that should be used to detect proxies.
     *
     * @var int
    *
    *protected $headers =
    *    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR |
    *    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST |
    *    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT |
    *    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO |
    *    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB;
    */

    protected $headers = [
        Request::HEADER_FORWARDED => 'FORWARDED',
        Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR => 'X_FORWARDED_FOR',
        Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST => 'X_FORWARDED_HOST',
        Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT => 'X_FORWARDED_PORT',
        Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO => 'X_FORWARDED_PROTO',
    ];
}
```

But I still get the same error.

I do not want to go around replacing "asset" with "secure_asset" everywhere, or make this conditional on production/test.  I would like the method prescribed by Laravel, in the linked page, to work.

How do I get this to work with the Bitnami docker image?

Thank you.

Comment: All you need to do is change the CSS from `http` to `https`. Secure pages (starting with https://) cannot load insecure assets (starting with http://). Using `asset()` should generate a URL using the current scheme, but perhaps that one file isn't using asset?

Comment: As I stated in the question, I'm aware of what the problem is, and Laravel has a documented solution for the precise issue.  However, that prescribed solution is not working in my context.  While manually doing other things to change it from https to http may be a band aid, it is not the solution.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too had the same issue, for me the follwing worked

So, first modify APP_URL (and APP_ENV if needed) in the .env file, if  you use assets helper, this shouldn't give any problem with the URL.

APP_ENV=production
APP_URL=https://example.com

Finally, add the following to the beginning of api.php or web.php:

```
if (App::environment('production')) {
    URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

In some cases, the app environment may be "local" instead of "production", in which case the two files should match on that value.

Comment: This was a while ago when I posted the question.  I've moved onto other things, but I look forward to coming back to this and trying your solution. Thank you!